# Does the [Bindable] metadata tag instantiate an Object by default?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I’m studying a demo code and it seems to me that an instance of a class is never instantiated, in particular I have this line:

```
<mx:Canvas ... currentState="{ model.state }">
```

...

```
[Bindable]
public var model:MainUIPresentationModel;
```

If that’s not the case, please tell me, I’ll post the complete code.

---

@Constantiner
Could it be:

```
<Injectors target="{ MainUI }">
    <PropertyInjector targetKey="model" source="{ MainUIPresentationModel }"/>
</Injectors>
```

?

Gosh this was a Mate question not a flex4 question. :( Sorry guys.

Comment: What instance of what class is suspected to not instantiated?

Comment: `model` of the `MainUIPresentationModel` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should understand that this declaration:

```
[Bindable]
public var model:MainUIPresentationModel;
```

is just declaration. The `[Bindable]` metatag just lets others to handle changes of your target object (`model`) automatically. But this metatag doesn't instantiate the value of the property you've declared.

So you need to assign a value to your declared property somewhere in your code corresponding your application's logic. Declaration is not enough.

Comment: Thank you. I’m examining [this demo code](http://mate.asfusion.com/assets/content/examples/intranet/srcview/), in the com.asfusion.intranet.shared.ui.views.MainUI.mxml folder there’s the complete code. I can’t find where the object is created. If you can find it (or tell me where it could be), answer accepted!

Comment: This code uses Mate's dependency injection feature. The answer is in [the following event map class](http://mate.asfusion.com/assets/content/examples/intranet/srcview/source/com/asfusion/intranet/shared/maps/MainMap.mxml.html) in the first injector of Injectors section :) You should use this code sample only if you understand Mate's principles because of heavy usage of Mate there :)

Comment: Ah! I have to learn Flex4, Actionscript 3 and Mate (other than PHP, Actionscript, Zend and Dojo) and build an academic planning system for my thesis on web technologies. And all that by the end of the month!